# How to change size (width & height) of a plot produced by PerformanceAnalytics package in RStudio?

Tags: r, plot, resize, performanceanalytics

Here is the code:

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(dret_data, main='Portfolio Performance',
                      Rf=0.015/252, plot.engine='default')
```

Plot looks compressed in the notebook, snippet below (**I would like to make it bigger**):
[image: compressed plot in the notebook]

When looking into the documentation nothing about plot resizing mentioned:

```
?charts.PerformanceSummary
```

Is there a way to work somehow around this issue and control witdh and height of the plot in the performanceAnalytics package in the R notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an RStudio notebook for the code & output, you'll need to adjust the fig.width and/or fig.height in the chunk(or document) options.

Below is the difference between fig.height 3 & 5:

````
```{r fig.height=3}
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

charts.PerformanceSummary(managers)
````

````
```{r fig.height=5}
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

charts.PerformanceSummary(managers)
````

[image]

*Edit:*

Making the title larger:

```
# Keep original par settings for later
opar <- par()

#change cex.main to whatever you want. Normal is 1.2 I think
par('cex.main' = 2)
#Plot now has larger title
charts.PerformanceSummary(managers)

# reset par settings 
par(opar)
```

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to change the title as well as it doesn't seem to change dynamically in sizing?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a way to do that after taking a look at the source code. https://github.com/cran/PerformanceAnalytics/blob/master/R/charts.PerformanceSummary.R

Comment: @DGomonov See edit in answer above to change title size.